# Generic alternative to Execute Around Method pattern

Tags: scala

I was looking for an implementation of the Execute Around method pattern in scala, and found the following (with my minor mods):

```
class Resource private() {
  private def dispose() { println("Cleaning up...") }

  def example = {
      println("Function body")
  }

}
object Resource {
  def using(codeBlock: Resource => Unit) {
    val run = new Resource
    try {
      codeBlock(run)
    }
    finally {
      run.dispose()
    }
  }
}


Resource.using { run =>  run.example }
```

Then I had second thoughts about using it for my particular application, since that's a lot of boilerplate code in all my classes.

I was wondering if the more experienced scala gurus were able to create a similar pattern, and wrap an entire object, calling a cleanup method when the object goes out of scope? This would be similar to the C# using() block, and I'd implement it by mixing in a Disposable trait to the objects that would support this method?

Example goal:

```
trait Disposable { def dispose }
class a extends Disposable

[some helper object unrelated to a?].using (a) { 

} // automatically call a.dispose() at end of scope?
```

Comment: garbage collection is one of the main value adds of the JVM.  If you want to be more efficient with your memory use I would try to optimize your code to use less objects, tweak your GC parameters, or use a different language

Comment: This is not specifically about garbage collection, but about resources that need to be closed elegantly. Some subsystems have specific closing sequences. Also, in some cases when dealing with pooled objects, I can return objects to the pool immediately. I actually do not care if the object really gets GC'ed or not, i just want the ability to run my cleanup code, then it can get GC'ed whenever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [blog post](http://illegalexception.schlichtherle.de/2012/07/19/try-with-resources-for-scala/) you can implement something like Java's try with resources this way:

```
class Loan[A <: AutoCloseable](resource: A) {
  def to[B](block: A => B) = {
    var t: Throwable = null
    try {
      block(resource)
    } catch {
      case x: Exception => t = x; throw x
    } finally {
      if (resource != null) {
        if (t != null) {
          try {
            resource.close()
          } catch {
            case y: Exception => t.addSuppressed(y)
          }
        } else {
          resource.close()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

object Loan {
  def loan[A <: AutoCloseable](resource: A) = new Loan(resource)
}
```

you would use it like this:

```
loan (new PrintWriter(new File("file"))) to (_ println "Hello world!\n")
```

Using the Java AutoCloseable interface for this means that your objects can be used in a Java try-with-resources block and that you can use your helper with standard Java AutoCloseable things like IO streams.